# Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName - JPA configs problems

Tags: maven, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1

I'm making a Maven EJB module, and i have troubles when i run tests using JUnit and Embedded GlassFish container.
EJB module consists of JPA entity and EJB stateless session bean.

whole project can be found here
https://github.com/muhamed-hassan/service-layer

persistence.xml

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence                                  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="custmgr-pu" transaction-type="JTA">

        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/customerCM_PU</jta-data-source>
        <class>model.Customer</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="MySQL"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>`

I'm getting this kind of exception

```
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName custmgr-pu`
```

Note that i put persistence.xml file under src/main/resources/META-INF directory, because i'm using a maven ejb project.

Comment: Can you give more info like, what errors you are getting? And post your error messages. And post code specific to your problem.

Comment: Can you  check whether persistence.xml  is present in EAR ?